# Resolve Services derived from base class using DryIoc

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dryioc

### Context

Within my Solution I have multiple Projetcs that define an EntityFramework Core `DbContext`. In my Entrypoint Project I would like to inject all instances of `DbContext` to be able to apply pending migrations for each of them.

The contexts are registered through `AddDbContext<T>(this IServiceCollection)` and are copied into the DryIoc using `Populate(this IContainer, IServiceCollection)`

### Example

```cs
class Base {};
class LeafOne : Base {};
class LeafTwo : Base {};

void Fun()
{
  var container = new Container();
  
  // Using Singleton to prove the point
  // This is meant to be a simplified version of the `AddDbContext` calls
  container.Register<LeafOne>(Reuse.Singleton);
  container.Register<LeafTwo>(Reuse.Singleton);

  container.ResolveMany<Base>(); // empty  
}
```

### Problem

How can I properly register the `Base` to resolve both singleton instances?

Here is what I tried:

```cs
container.RegisterMapping<Base, LeafOne>();
container.RegisterMapping<Base, LeafTwo>();
container.ResolveMany<Base>(); // resolves only the LeafOne instance
```

```cs
container.Register<Base, LeafOne>(Reuse.Singleton);
container.Register<Base, LeafTwo>(Reuse.Singleton);
container.ResolveMany<Base>(); 
// resolves instances for both leaf classes, but -as expected- 
// they are different instances than the ones registered in
// the beginning
```

```cs
container.RegisterDelegate<Base>(ctx => ctx.Resolve<LeafOne>());
container.RegisterDelegate<Base>(ctx => ctx.Resolve<LeafTwo>());
container.ResolveMany<Base>();
// actually works for this example, but won't for DbContext because
// its trying to call a parameterless constructor for `Base` on resolve
// which doesn't exist
```

Is there a simple way to alias a type for it's parent class?

Comment: I am not sure why your attempt with RegisterDelegate did not work - I have added a couple of cases using it and making Base abstract - works for me https://dotnetfiddle.net/vigkVP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RegisterMapping` should work but it won't in the current DryIoc <=4.3.4
because `RegisterMapping` uses the `IfAlreadyRegistered.Keep` by default, keeping the first Base registration and rejecting the second.

Here is [the issue to fix it](https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/issues/314).

Until then you need to register with the service keys - **it maybe even better in your specific case** because it will hide the `Base` from the normal resolution but will keep them resolved or injected as a collection.

Here [the code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vigkVP)

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using DryIoc;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var container = new Container();

        container.Register<LeafOne>(Reuse.Singleton);
        container.Register<LeafTwo>(Reuse.Singleton);
        
        // the keys are required in the DryIoc <=4.3.4 because RegisterMapping uses the IfAlreadyRegistered.Keep by default,
        // keeping the first Base registration and rejecting the second
        container.RegisterMapping<Base, LeafOne>(serviceKey: 1); 
        container.RegisterMapping<Base, LeafTwo>(serviceKey: 2);

        var bases = container.ResolveMany<Base>().ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(bases.Length); // outputs 2
    }
    
    class Base {};
    class LeafOne : Base {};
    class LeafTwo : Base {};
}
```

### Update: DryIoc v4.4 is released and RegisterMapping does not require service key

This should work now:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using DryIoc;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var container = new Container();

        container.Register<LeafOne>(Reuse.Singleton);
        container.Register<LeafTwo>(Reuse.Singleton);
        
        // Works in DryIoc v4.4
        container.RegisterMapping<Base, LeafOne>(); 
        container.RegisterMapping<Base, LeafTwo>();

        var bases = container.ResolveMany<Base>().ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(bases.Length); // outputs 2
    }
    
    class Base {};
    class LeafOne : Base {};
    class LeafTwo : Base {};
}
```